# What's the word for driving together to work, but not in the same car

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose you person A and person B work at the same place. You meet at a certain point and both drive to that point. Then from that point you drive together to work in your separate cars. Is there a word for this? It's like carpooling, but not exactly the same.

To fit single-word-requests:

Person A and Person B "insert word here" everyday to work.

Comment: Does this actually happen anywhere? If it is extremely rare, there may not (yet?) be a word for it.

Comment: I'm with Tim -- not common enough to have a name, except perhaps in a few localities where there is some sort of reason to do this.  Even when my wife and I leave at the same time in separate cars, to travel into town to the same destination, we don't stay together.  Traffic lights and the like make this impractical.  The only times I've done this sort of thing was when traveling cross-country, and even then the tendency was simply to rendezvous at each meal or gas stop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't commute specific, but I would suggest **driving in convoy**. [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/convoy) gives:

> **convoy** *noun*
>
> - a group of vehicles or ships that travel together, especially for protection: *A convoy of trucks containing supplies was sent to the famine area.*
>
> **in convoy**
>
> - travelling one behind another in a row: *Shall we all drive to the party in convoy so we don't get lost?*

Comment: *Cause we got a little ol' convoy / Rockin' through the night. / Yeah, we got a little ol' convoy, / Ain't she a beautiful sight?*  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sd5ZLJWQmss

Comment: Absolutely can't resist:  "Pig Pen, this here's the Cobalt Duck.
And I'm about to put the hammer down!"

Answer (score 3):

Some thoughts on this:

> A and B **escort** each other to work everyday.
>   A and B **accompany** each other to work everyday.
>   A and B **drive along** to work everyday. [[ seems to be a better alternative ]]
>   A and B **drive together** to work everyday. [[ seems to be the best alternative ]]
>   A and B **follow** each other to work everyday.
>   A and B **go with** each other to work everyday.

Comment: I'm waiting if someone else answers the question even better before I mark your answer as the accepted answer